# How to get line charts displayed in Power BI for the given requirement?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have this table in Excel and I want line charts(generated as shown in the image) which change when you click on a project in the slicer. The 1 2 3 in the x-axis represents a 3 of the quarters in a year. How to get this done?

[image]

Comment: did you try using matrix instead of plain table visual? i feel like this should do the trick since matrix allow you to have multiple fields as columns/rows

Comment: What specifically is it that you need help with?

Comment: @Marcus I don’t know what to put for x-axis and y-axis. It’s confusing.

Comment: You put your quarter column on the X-axis and your measures on the Y-axis.

Comment: @Marcus but how to get a graph for each project for Process, Compliance, Delivery and Average seperately using a slicer for Projects?

Comment: Add more visualizations?